# If Else Statement Doesn't Return the Else Statement

Tags: python, if-statement

```
    reject_numberList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
resend_numberList = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

for i in range(6):
    try:
        print("Is",reject_numberList[i], "resend?")
        if(reject_numberList[i] < resend_numberList[i] and resend_numberList[i] == reject_numberList[i+1]):
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Here is my code. There are some numbers rejected and resent. But number 6 doesn't return 'False'. And Here is the output:

```
Is 1 resend?
True
Is 2 resend?
True
Is 3 resend?
True
Is 4 resend?
True
Is 5 resend?
True
Is 6 resend?

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What is wrong with number 6?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? Why is your exception handler empty?

Comment: That last item generated an IndexError (due to the `reject_numberList[i+1]` expression), but your `except` clause covered this up.

Comment: Don't suppress the `IndexError` and you will see. `reject_numberList[i+1]` is the problem.

Comment: because `list index out of range`

Comment: @jarmod I didn't noticed that, thank you I will edit it

Comment: try/except that mask exceptions are considered a bad coding practice (i.e. your pass in except).  See [The Most Diabolical Python Antipattern](https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/).  The issue is code errors go undetected.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you

Comment: @DarrylG thank you for information source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through created arrays which have same amount of elements.

The cause of the issue is the `if` part:

```
if(reject_numberList[i] < resend_numberList[i] and resend_numberList[i] == reject_numberList[i+1]):
```

Your `reject_numberList[i+1]` will go out of bound.

tldr:
Your `i` value in last iteration is 6 and `reject_numberList[i+1]` wants to get a 7th element of `reject_numberList` which doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```py
reject_numberList[i+1]
```

In last step goes out of bounds and raises `IndexError` which you catch and `pass` so no exception is raised and program reaches its end.

Answer (score 0):

Since you look-ahead on the reject_numberList, you are getting an exception - index out of bounds for 6 - there is not item in the array after it.  CHeck first if ti < reject_numberList.size - 1, if not, return false without checking that item.

Answer (score 0):

You are causing an index error with this code: `reject_numberList[i+1]`

This problem stems from the fact that i ends as 5. Therefore, 6 would be the index of `reject_numberList`.

Since lists begin at index 0, the list `['1','2','3','4','5','6']` will not accept an index of 6; 6 is outside the list's range.

Imagine this:

```
['1','2','3','4','5','6']
# 0   1   2   3   4   5  <- There is no sixth position, since we started at 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an index out of range error because python begins its counting at 0...there are 6 elements in the array (not sure why your numbers are stored as characters) but to python there are elements 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. To avoid problems try

```
for i in range(len(rejectNumber_list))
```